# drag and drop WPF combobox item to a textbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-and-drop

I want to drag and drop a  item of WPF combo Box to  a WPF Textbox.

Can u tell me how to achieve this?

Thanks in adv

Comment: There are multiple options you could use, using out-of-the-box functionality is shown here http://wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html

Comment: I m following this tutorial and it is really effective , but this when i start dragging my comboBox get clsoed automatically and i cant drag an item from it, while tutorial uses listBox so closing issue is not with List Box.Any guess to resolve this closing issue ?

Comment: rewrite default template, it has an Popup, called PART_Popup as I remember, and rewrite its StaysOpen property to true. may be its help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextBox have AllowDrop true by default , the only thing required is to code drag functionally of DropBox Item